# Return true if any variation of strings matches in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, if-statement

I have these possible folder names in a url:

```
firstname+lastname
firstname-lastname
firstname lastname
Firstname+Lastname
```

I need a way to catch these, the common element would be firstname and lastname (so I don't care about the + - or space), but I do need to convert them `toLowerCase();`

Can this be done with a regex? (I am not particularly sophisticated in my use of regex, I can use basic match() functions.

My other thought was to store these variants in an array and return true if any of the items match one of the array items.

I was looking at this solution: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/testing_for_a_v

In this case though I think my array and statement would look something like this:

```
var strArray = ['firstname','lastname'];
strArray.toLowerCase();
var href = document.location.href;
var secondaryDir = href.split("/")[4];

if (secondaryDir in strArray){
  console.log('Its true!');
  // do magic here 
}
```

Not sure if there is a better way to test this?

(I've tagged this question with jquery as that is what I am using, although I think all the code here is vanilla js).

***EDIT***

Actually I don't need to worry about converting the array to lower case as I can do this against the secondaryDir variable (I think).

Comment: Just a note: You cannot use a regex in javascript to turn your input to lower or upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would be a regex solution to this problem:

```
var pattern = '/([a-zA-Z]*)[\+\- ]([a-zA-Z]*)/';
var matches = pattern.exec(text);
```

With `text` being the string containing firstname and lastname.
`matches[1]` should contain firstname, and `matches[2]` lastname.

What the regex does is matching every letter before `+`,`-` or , as well as matching every letter that follows.

Comment: thanks I've never used exec but I will give this a try.

Comment: Is it possible to put this in a fiddle? I cannot seem to get it to work. If I can see matches[0] and matches[1] in the console it might help, but I will keep trying of course :)

Comment: I removed the quote marks from pattern and now at least I am getting something in the console: var pattern = /([a-zA-Z]*)[\+\- ]([a-zA-Z]*)/;